# Python 3 Spyder Xarray: Why is the same NetCDF file loaded everytime (within a loop, and defining different variables)

Tags: python-3.x, caching, spyder, netcdf, python-xarray

I want to load the files here: https://thredds.aodn.org.au/thredds/catalog/IMOS/SRS/SST/ghrsst/L3S-3d/day/1992/catalog.html and store them in a list using xarray. But instead of being on thredds, the files are saved on a remote server that I mount locally and access.

Here is my code to load in the files in a loop:

```
    # 'file_paths_on_server' below is a list of file paths

    # load in data
    data = []
    for n in range(len(file_paths_on_server)):
        ds = xr.open_dataset(file_paths_on_server[n], cache=False).load();
        data.append(ds)
        ds.close()
```

However, the same NetCDF file (the first one in the loop) is loaded in at every iteration. So I have a list of the same NetCDF file loaded in.

I tried the following outside of a loop too:

```
a = xr.open_dataset(file_paths_on_server[0], cache=False).load()
b = xr.open_dataset(file_paths_on_server[1], cache=False).load()
```

But both a and b are the same NetCDF file loaded in as a dataset. I have checked that `file_paths_on_server' varies, and it does.

I am using Python 3 and the Spyder IDE.

```
xarray 2022.11.0
netCDF4 1.5.7
Spyder 5.1.5
Python 3.9.7 64-bit 
Qt 5.9.7 
PyQt5 5.9.2 
Windows 10
```

It seems like an issue with the cache, either for Spyder, Python or xarray?

Comment: My understanding is that caching will only impact this if the file path is the same. Are you totally suture these are different files and different files? I doubt this can be caused by xarray. This would be a very large bug which they should have spotted

Comment: Yeah sorry but there’s no way this is true. Restart your kernel and check your code carefully. Also how are you checking to see if the files are the same? We can’t help you without all of your code.

Comment: My (unchanged) code now works today. Not sure why. I did try shutting down Spyder and opening again yesterday but I was still getting the same results described above. However, I am now on a different computer perhaps with different package versions. Is this the reason? will test it again when I am next using the other computer.